# Adding a comma between JSON objects in a datafile with Python?

Tags: python, json, python-re, txt

I have large file (about 3GB) which contains what looks like a JSON file but isn't because it lacks commas (,) between "observations" or JSON objects (I have about 2 million of these "objects" in my data file).

For example, this is what I have:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$id": "fh37fc3huc3"
    },
    "messageid": "4757724838492485088139042828",
    "attachments": [],
    "usernameid": "47284592942",
    "username": "Alex",
    "server": "475774810304151552",
    "text": "Must watch",
    "type": "462050823720009729",
    "datetime": "2018-08-05T21:20:20.486000+00:00",
    "type": {
        "$numberLong": "0"
    }
}

{
    "_id": {
        "$id": "23453532dwq"
    },
    "messageid": "232534",
    "attachments": [],
    "usernameid": "273342",
    "usernameid": "Alice",
    "server": "475774810304151552",
    "text": "https://www.youtube.com/",
    "type": "4620508237200097wd29",
    "datetime": "2018-08-05T21:20:11.803000+00:00",
    "type": {
        "$numberLong": "0"
    }
```

And this is what I want (the comma between "observations"):

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$id": "fh37fc3huc3"
    },
    "messageid": "4757724838492485088139042828",
    "attachments": [],
    "username": "Alex",
    "server": "475774810304151552",
    "type": {
        "$numberLong": "0"
    }
},

{
    "_id": {
        "$id": "23453532dwq"
    },
    "messageid": "232534",
    "attachments": [],
    "usernameid": "Alice",
    "server": "475774810304151552",
    "type": {
        "$numberLong": "0"
    }
```

This is what I tried but it doesn't give me a comma where I need it:

```
import re

with open('dataframe.txt', 'r') as input, open('out.txt', 'w') as output:
    output.write("[")
    for line in input:
        line = re.sub('', '},{', line)
        output.write('    '+line)
    output.write("]")
```

What can I do so that I can add a comma between each JSON object in my datafile?

Comment: Note that even with the commas, it is still not legal JSON.

Comment: What you *do* have is a stream of valid JSON objects. The `jq` utility can easily convert it into a single JSON array of objects: `jq -s '.' dataframe.txt`. There is a library of `jq` bindings for Python, but unfortunately it would require reading the entire JSON into memory. Ideally, you would use a Python streaming JSON library that could handle a stream of objects as well, but I don't have any good recommendation for one.

Comment: If the line is just a closing brace and nothing else, add a comma after.  But don't do that on the very last line.

Comment: Given the size, if it’s formatted with **precisely** this format, I’d shoot for `sed` or `awk` rather than Python if speed was any way a concern.  As per John Gordon.  Trim off last comma or check there is something coming up next line in sed awk.

Answer (score 1):

This solution presupposes that none of the fields in JSON contains neither `{` nor `}`.

If we assume that there is at least one blank line between JSON dictionaries, an idea: let's maintain unclosed curly brackets count (`{`) as `unclosed_count`; and if we meet an empty line, we add the coma once.

Like this:

```py
with open('test.json', 'r') as input_f, open('out.json', 'w') as output_f:
    output_f.write("[")
    unclosed_count = 0
    comma_after_zero_added = True
    for line in input_f:
        unclosed_count_change = line.count('{') - line.count('}')
        unclosed_count += unclosed_count_change
        if unclosed_count_change != 0:
            comma_after_zero_added = False
        if line.strip() == '' and unclosed_count == 0 and not comma_after_zero_added:
            output_f.write(",\n")
            comma_after_zero_added = True
        else:
            output_f.write(line)
    output_f.write("]")
```

Comment: What if any of the fields in the json contain a `{` or `}`?

Comment: Doesn't looks like case of OP, but the truth is that if it happen — my solution wouldn't work. Should mention that, I'll add it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to view your data is that you have multiple json records separated by whitespace. You can use the stdlib `JSONDecoder` to read each record, then strip whitespace and repeat til done. The decoder reads a record from a string and tells you how far it got. Apply that iteratively to the data until all is consumed. This is far less risky than making a bunch of assumptions about what data is contained in the json itself.

```
import json

def json_record_reader(filename):
    with open(filename, encoding="utf-8") as f:
        txt = f.read().lstrip()
    decoder = json.JSONDecoder()
    result = []
    while txt:
        data, pos = decoder.raw_decode(txt)
        result.append(data)
        txt = txt[pos:].lstrip()
    return result
    
print(json_record_reader("data.json"))
```

Considering the size of your file, a memory mapped text file may be the better option.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming sufficient memory, you can parse such a stream one object at a time using `json.JSONDecoder.raw_decode` directly, instead of using `json.loads`.

```
>>> x = '{"a": 1}\n{"b": 2}\n'  # Hypothetical output of open("dataframe.txt").read()
>>> decoder = json.JSONDecoder()
>>> x = '{"a": 1}\n{"b":2}\n'
>>> decoder.raw_decode(x)
({'a': 1}, 8)
>>> decoder.raw_decode(x, 9)
({'b': 2}, 16)
```

The output of `raw_decode` is a tuple containing the first JSON value decoded and the position in the string where the remaining data starts. (Note that `json.loads` just creates an instance of `JSONDecoder`, and calls the `decode` method, which just calls `raw_decode` and artificially raises an exception if the entire input isn't consumed by the first decoded value.)

A little extra work is involved; note that you can't *start* decoding with whitespace, so you'll have to use the returned index to detect where the next value starts, following any additional whitespace at the returned index.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that the only place you will find a blank line is between two dicts, then you can go ahead with your current idea, after you fix its execution. For every line, check if it's empty. If it isn't, write it as-is. If it is, write a comma instead

```
with open('dataframe.txt', 'r') as input_file, open('out.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    output_file.write("[")
    for line in input_file:
        if line.strip():
            output_file.write(line)
        else:
            output_file.write(",")
    output_file.write("]")
```

If you cannot guarantee that any blank line must be replaced by a comma, you need a different approach.
You want to replace a close-bracket, followed by an empty line (or multiple whitespace), followed by an open-bracket, with `},{`.

You can keep track of the previous two lines in addition to the current line, and if these are `"}"`, `""`, and `"{"` in that order, then write a comma before writing the `"{"`.

```
from collections import deque

with open('dataframe.txt', 'r') as input_file, open('out.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    last_two_lines = deque(maxlen=2)
    output_file.write("[")
    for line in input_file:
        line_s = line.strip()
        if line_s == "{" and list(last_two_lines) == ["}", ""]:
            output_file.write("," + line)
        else:
            output_file.write(line)
        last_two_lines.append(line_s)
```

Alternatively, if you want to stick with regex, then you could do

```
with open('dataframe.txt') as input_file:
    file_contents = input_file.read()

repl_contents = re.sub(r'\}(\s+)\{', r'},\1{', file_contents)

with open('out.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    output_file.write(repl_contents)
```

Here, the regex `r"\}(\s+)\{"` matches the pattern we're looking for (`\s+` matches multiple whitespace characters, and captures them in group 1, which we then use in the replacement string as `\1`.

Note that you will need to read and run `re.sub` on the entire file, which will be slow.

Comment: Just curious, had you ever run a meaningful `re.sub` on a 1GB+ string successfully? I'm not joking, really curious.

Comment: @YevgeniyKosmak no, and I would  not recommend it, which is why it's the second (now third) approach in my answer and I included the caveat that it will be slow.